# Перезагрузить страницу после выбора города

Tags: javascript

Проблема в том, что `window.location.reload()` и перенаправление на ту же ссылку не помогает. (((

Может, кто-то что-то посоветует?

Принцип работы:  
При загрузке страницы выводит переменную региона из сессии, после изменения js'oм (ajax) id региона нужно перезагрузить страницу так, чтоб этот новый id применился на всю страницу, а то она вроде обновляет, но значения функций, что имеют в параметрах этот id, не изменяются, а если я руками в браузере обновляю, все нормально работает. ((

Comment: Разобрался. ))) Нужно было переадресацию делать в успешной отработке ajax. )))

Comment: @yazadjidima, а как и где вы храните id на странице? В каких-то атрибутах элементов или в скрытых полях формы, или еще как-то? И нужно ли их вообще держать id прописанными на странице? Ведь есть cookie или Local Storage.

Comment: @yazadjidima, По возможности публикуйте ответы на форуме, они могут помочь многим в будущем.